# Options to re-organize test files in which one class depends on another class?

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm reorganizing the test cases of a legacy php project to test suites and encounter the problem of testing a class that depends on another class. Here is the original directory layout of the tests folder.

```
tests/
   |  
   +- models/
   |     | ClassATest.php
   |     | ClassBTest.php
   |     | ...
   +- controllers/
   |     | ...
```

Currently, there is no test suite. Each test is run separately.

To reorganize these tests, as a start, I create *phpunit.xml* and group the tests into suites like below.

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="...">
    <testsuite name="Models">
        <directory>./models</directory>
    </testsuite>
    ...
</phpunit>
```

Now I get into trouble. We have two models, ClassA and ClassB, in which a method of ClassB depends on ClassA.

```
class ClassA
{
    public function getValue(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $a = new ClassA();
        $x = $a->getValue(...);
        // do something with $x
        ...
    }
 }
```

Here, I think we all see the problem when it comes to testing. To mock ClassA::getValue(), *ClassBTest.php* has (re-)defined ClassA like the following.

**ClassBTest.php**

```
class ClassA
{
    public function getValue(...)
    {
        return 'a mock value';
    }
}

class ClassBTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDoSomething()
    {
        $b = new ClassB();
        // Make an assertion with $b->doSomething()
    }
}
```

So, when we test each model separately, it works. But when run in a suite, it causes an error since now ClassA is re-declared at some point of the running process, and phpunit is terminated.

My question is how to deal with this situation. I have tried some options.

- Removing the re-defined classes in the test files and using dependency injection. This way is not preferred since we don't want to modify the model classes for dependency injection.
- Using the group annotation to exclude such test files as *ClassBTest.php* and running the excluded files separately. This option is not convenient.

Can we configure phpunit to run a group of files in a process and another group of files in another process? Can PHP load and unload a class dynamically at runtime? If you have any other options, please suggest.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can PHP load and unload a class dynamically at runtime? If you have any other options, please suggest.

Yes. It's the last resort for testing code you can't refactor. Take a look at [the runkit extension, method_rename](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.runkit-function-rename.php). You could rename the orignal method you want to "mock". Create your mock function and rename it back after the test.

The newer [**`php test helpers`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-test-helpers) also offers a rename functionality.

---

Alternatively you can use ["runInIsolation" / "process-isolation"](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html). Every test case will be run in another PHP process. If you only define those classes withing the test case you won't run into "already defined" issues.

---

**A third option that doesn't rely on extensions or spawing a lot of php process that make your test suite slow**

It might seem a bit hackisch but just to offer all options:

```
class ClassB
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $a = new ClassA();
        $x = $a->getValue(...);
        // do something with $x
        ...
    }
 }
```

without **much** refactoring you could to the following:

class ClassB
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        $a = $this->getClassA();
        $x = $a->getValue(...);
        // do something with $x
        ...
    }

```
protected function getClassA() {
    if(!$this->classA) { 
        return new ClassA(); 
    } 
    return $this->classA;
}

public function setClassAForTesting(ClassA $classA) {
    $this->classA = $classA;
}
```

}

This **will** clutter your code base with "code for testing" but using `setter injection` allows you to use dependency injection for testing while your production code will work just as before.

This method requires some work but it, in my experience, much more sustainable than using PHP Extensions to hack in behavior.

Comment: Thanks, edorian! Gotta discuss with the team between using php extension and refactoring the models. Probably we would go with your first option. Would it be nice if phpunit allowed us to run each group of files in a separate process? Should we make a feature request to Sebastian Bergmann ;)